# Return Javascript child array based on parent filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

Disclaimer: I know some Java but almost nothing about Javascript and have about 2 days to fix someone else's issues, of which this is one small part.

I have a nested array. I know the shop number, but need to get an array of only the parts in that shop.

```
"shops": [
    {
      "shopID": "15231",
      "city": "Anytown",
      "state": "MO",
      "inventory": [
        {
          "description": "filter",
          "partnumber": "MGL57047",
          "shelf": "Z",
        },
        {
          "description": "filter",
          "partnumber": "84060",
          "shelf": "A",
        }
    },
    {
      "shopID": "15232",
      "city": "Springfield",
      "state": "IL",
      "inventory": [
        {
          "description": "filter",
          "partnumber": "MGL57048",
          "shelf": "B",
        },
        {
          "description": "filter",
          "partnumber": "84061",
          "shelf": "A",
        }
    }
```

Here's what I tried:

```
const enteredShopID = '15231' // This isn't hard-coded in my app.
// Pull the list of all consumables for the current shop
var currentShop = application.data.shops.filter(s => s.shopID == enteredShopID)
```

This gets me an array with the shop and all of the inventory for that shop, but I need an array of the inventory. I tried

```
var currentShop = application.data.shops.inventory.filter(s => s.shopID == enteredShopID)
```

but that didn't work. Really, I'm just fumbling here. Is there a way to make the latter statement work, and somehow refer to the shopID of the parent?

Comment: If the ids are unique, it should be `.find()` instead of `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map()` after the filter.

```
var currentShop = application.data.shops
   .filter(s => s.shopID == enteredShopID)[0]

// checking if the current shop is actually null because no shops matched the ID
var currentShopInventory = (currentShop || {}).inventory || []
```

or use `find()`

```
// Note: If you use find(), there's a chance that there is no matching object
// So you'll have to check for that before you access the "inventory" key
// Otherwise you'll get "Cannot access 'inventory' of null"
var matchingShop = application.data.shops
   .find(s => s.shopID == enteredShopID)

// Doing the checking here using an "or" if the matchingShop is null
var currentShop = matchingShop || {}
var currentShopInventory = currentShop.inventory || []
```